# Vue 2 input name attribute with a multidimensional value

Tags: vuejs2

How do I update this input to work with Vue.js 2?

```
<input value="{{item.id}}" type="text" name="emails[{{$index}}]['id']" />
```

This is as far as I've got:

```
<input :value="item.id" type="text" class="form-control" name="emails[{{$index}}]['id']" />
```

I'm not sure how to update the name attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For name as well you have to use v-bind or in short `:` like following:

```
<input :value="item.id" type="text" class="form-control" 
  :name="emails[$index]['id']" />
```

Comment: Ah! Where I was getting stuck was with inside the name I didn't know I could use $index instead. Thank you so much!